# jQuery to extract 'Click Me' from <a href="http://example.com">Click Me</a>

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

My code currently looks like this..

```
$(row).children("td").eq(index).html()
```

and this gives me:

```
<a href="http://example.com">Click This</a>
```

From the console taking the above element

```
var item = $(row).children("td").eq(index);
item[0].innerText() // outputs "Click Me" but doesn't work in my app.
```

But this doesn't work in the js in my Rails app and generates an error.

How do I structure this code so it properly outputs 'Click Me' as Im wanting?

For background I'm developing a Rails4 App and using coffeescript, but I don't think that's immediately relevant here.

[Edit 1:]
When I use this code:

$(row).children("td").eq(index)[0].Text()

Produces the error:

```
'Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function'
```

It's a table sorter that I'm building. I'm addressing the fact that the sorter is working fine for table entries built from plain text, eg the City field, but that it's incorrectly sorting the Name field as it is processing the whole A field string.

I need to be able to have it extract the text field within an address tag  if there is one and otherwise just sort on the text field if the sort field is not within an address tag.

Comment: I would say that sharing the content of the generated error *is* immediately relevant here.

Comment: Did you try anything at all, should be as easy as `item.text()`, and `innerText` is not a function, it's a property.

Comment: Wow ouch. Ok looks like I could be asking this better. 1. Yes I've tried a bunch of stuff before posting. 2. I tried .text() also. I'll post the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following:

```
$(row).children("td").eq(index).text()
```

Here is the relevant doc:
http://api.jquery.com/text/

Comment: Yep exactly what I needed. I was so close.